# Reuse Document Library inside custom app

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-application

I was wondering if it is possible to reuse the original document library app inside a custom app.

It's my first time considering developing a SharePoint app in order to replace an old PHP app, and the document management of the document library app correspond to the user needs but i have to add the others features of the old application inside the sharepoint in order to replace it.

Comment: You can add this library to the app. What do you mean by reuse Out of the box Library app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you can "reuse" the OTB SharePoint document library app. You will want to take a look at [Working With Folders and Files with REST](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/rest/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) to gain an understanding of how to do CRUD operations on document libraries.

Also, if you haven't already, you will want to go over the new [SharePoint Framework](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) for developing custom apps using Microsoft's new development model.